# rust poem route with variable path segments

Tags: rust, rust-poem

I have an HTTP endpoint in rust using poem::openapi.  I would like a single handler for a variable segment path.

```
#[OpenApi]
impl NvApi {
    #[oai(path = "/:namespace/:id", method = "get")]
    async fn get(
        &self,
        nv: Data<&SharedHandle>,
        namespace: Path<String>,
        id: Path<String>,
    ) -> Result<GetResponse, poem::Error> {
        log::debug!("get {}/{}", namespace.as_str(), id.as_str());
...
...
...
}
```

I would like the code above to handle paths like `/mynamespace/mydomain/myid` as well as `/mynamespace/myid` - an arbitrary number of segments loaded into the namespace variable but always loading the trailing segment into the 'id' variable.

I've seen references to "*path" in the poem repo but can't find any docs or examples of wildcard.  I'd like to use the pattern above as my SharedHandle impl is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly possible.

The path parser in `poem` [breaks after encountering a wildcard token](https://github.com/poem-web/poem/blob/v1.3.30/poem/src/route/internal/radix_tree.rs#L106) which means it cannot be used to match in the middle of a path.

The best workaround would be to use a regex that matches all path segments except the final segment. In code, that would hypothetically appear as:

```rs
    #[oai(path = "/:namespace<.+(?=/)>/:id", method = "get")]
    async fn get(&self, ...) ...
```

but `poem` uses the `regex` crate which [does not support lookaheads](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/issues/127) (needed to ignore the last slash).

Instead, you will have to use a regex with no lookaheads and manually remove the trailing slash:

```rs
#[OpenApi]
impl Api {
    #[oai(path = "/:namespace<.+/>:id", method = "get")]
    async fn get(
        &self,
        ...
        namespace: Path<String>,
        id: Path<String>,
    ) -> ... {
        // GET /a/b/c
        println!("{}", namespace.to_string()); // a/b/
        println!("{}", id.to_string());        // c
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is exactly what I wanted.  One minor downside is the swagger UI documents it properly but can't format working requests anymore:
it can't format the requests from the UI form, ie: 
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8800/api/{namespace<.+}/>:id' \
  -H 'accept: application/json; charset=utf-8'